# How to make correct use of sshpass along with password and different port?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I am building a job in jenkins in which i need to copy the folders and file from jenkins server to another server. The server has port 802 and password= "PASSWORD" how to copy folder to another server?

```
sshpass -p'PASSWORD'scp -P 802 $SSH_OPTS  -r $WORKSPACE/target/abc.war root@2xx.xx.xxx.xx:/root/war/

Usage: sshpass [-f|-d|-p|-e] [-hV] command parameters
   -f filename   Take password to use from file
   -d number     Use number as file descriptor for getting password
   -p password   Provide password as argument (security unwise)
   -e            Password is passed as env-var "SSHPASS"
   With no parameters - password will be taken from stdin

   -P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password prompt
   -v            Be verbose about what you're doing
   -h            Show help (this screen)
   -V            Print version information
At most one of -f, -d, -p or -e should be used
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using expect script, you can use the below code:

## !/usr/bin/expect -f

## Usage sshsudologin.expect (host) (ssh user) (ssh password)

set timeout 10

spawn scp -r "/folder_to_copy/" [lindex $argv 1]@[lindex $argv 0]:"destination_dir/"

expect "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }

expect eof

Comment: could you explain this @piyush sachdeva . I couldnt understand it  properly

Comment: I provided you the code of expect script it works just like bash script, use this code in your usecase to automate the copy of file/folder from one server to another.create a file test.expect and execute it with expect test.expect command where argv 0,1 and 2 are parameters passed through command line while running the script just like $1, $2 $3 in shell.

Comment: I also don't understand this, please explain